# Password store in wordpress database in table wp_users

Tags: wordpress, passwords, password-encryption, password-hash, password-storage

How is the password being stored in the table `wp_users` in wordpress database? I wanted to know what is the algorithm being used to stre password values in the column `user_pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses [php's crypt method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) to hash the password. Here's the method used to hash the password in Wordpress's source code: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2651ff3ae805321432bc6d9eac3d62269c937077/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L236

Wordpress [generates a salt string](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2651ff3ae805321432bc6d9eac3d62269c937077/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L184) on which to bash the hashing for this particular method in that same class.